# How do you get GPFlow running under Tensorflow 2?

Tags: gpflow

I realize the Tensorflow 1 -> 2 transition is still ongoing for GPFlow, but I'm wondering what the best way to use GPFlow under TF2 currently is. I'm hoping to teach with it in the next few weeks, and would like to work in TF2. Presently, its even difficult to get the two installed together. I've tried various combinations of the TF2 RC1, GPflow master, nightlies, etc. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

GPflow has been ported to the *TensorFlow 2.0*. To install it you need to checkout to the `awav/gpflow-2.0` branch and follow instructions in *README.md*: https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/tree/awav/gpflow-2.0#install-gpflow-20-beta-version.

Update (4 Feb 2020): GPflow 2.0 is available in `develop` branch. There is also a 2.0 release candidate.